# How do I comment and edit on an activity post?

Tags: trello, comments

I write something on a card in the Activity window and press "Comment". It then posts on the card. Later I would like to have other people comment on the post, or edit it myself or comment on it myself.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Currently you can delete a comment (and re-add a new one), but you cannot edit a comment, or comment on a comment.

Answer (score 0):

... and to state the obvious:

"Now, later I would like to have other people comment on the post, [...] or commennt on it myself. "

Other people, and you, comment on the post by adding more comments :)